# Wordpress - Move posts *along with categories* to a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

TLDR: I've been able to bulk migrate 1,000 posts from Posts to a custom post type I created "News," but need to map the old categories to the new taxonomy I've created. I still have other blog posts so don't want to move all categories, just some.

**What I've done (code below):**
- Created custom post type ("News")
- Created categories taxonomy for custom post type (also named "Categories")
- Used "Post Type Switcher" to migrate Posts to News

**Need to do:**
- Have same categories from posts show on News page.

**functions.php:**

```
function cw_post_type_news() {
  $supports = array(
    'title', // post title
    'editor', // post content
    'author', // post author
    'thumbnail', // featured images
    'excerpt', // post excerpt
    'custom-fields', // custom fields
    'comments', // post comments
    'revisions', // post revisions
  );

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('News', 'plural'),
    'singular_name' => _x('News', 'singular'),
    'menu_name' => _x('News', 'admin menu'),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x('News', 'admin bar'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new post'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New news'),
    'new_item' => __('New news'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit news'),
    'view_item' => __('View news'),
    'all_items' => __('All news'),
    'search_items' => __('Search news'),
    'not_found' => __('No news found.'),
  );

  $args = array(
    'supports' => $supports,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
  );
  register_post_type('news', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'cw_post_type_news');

/* Add categories (custom taxonomy) for news =============================== */
function my_taxonomies_news() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used categories', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'news_category', 'news', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_news', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. You just need to export all of your posts from Admin Dashboard > Tools > Export. You can follow these steps: [EXPORT WORDPRESS POSTS TO CUSTOM POST TYPE](https://webdogs.com/blog/export-wordpress-posts-custom-post-type/)

I have followed same steps. try it and let me know if you need any help from my side.